# She and I , I and She , Him and I

Tags: subjects

which one is better ?

She and I collected some things from store.

I and She collected some requipment from there.

Him and I

me and him

Im confused

Comment: It's always "x and I", (almost) never "I and x".  Can you turn your "him" examples into full sentences?

Comment: @snailboat I agree, and I would not go as far as to call it ungrammatical. It's just not euphonic, like saying "white and black film" instead of "black and white film". Sometimes "I" occurs first, and then the speaker adds other people to bolster his case, "I and she both feel that ..." (speaker was going to say I feel that; added another person at the last moment).

Comment: Also, if it's clear who "she" or "he" is, consider using "we" instead.

Comment: @Kaz I agree with you in principle, but I think that most native speakers use *she and I* and *me and him* (and I suspect that I do this as a device I learned as a child to remember the difference between the pronouns) I agree with you because I cannot think of any rule that strictly forbids constructing it in other ways. As long as we're using *subject* and *object* pronouns appropriately, I can't see myself actually objecting to it's use; I'm simply saying that one comes out more naturally. I don't think the order is critical here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ***Him and I*** is completely wrong. *Him* is an *object* pronoun.

The same is true of *her*. They're both object pronouns, and thus cannot be used to represent subjects. *Him and I*, *I and Him*, *Her and I*, and *I and her* are incorrect.

As for *She/He and I* versus *I and s/he*, I think that's insignificant enough to be at the discretion of the speaker.

> **She and I** are going shopping with *them*. **He and I** are playing football at **his and her** house. With **whom** do **she and I
>   agree**?

Personally, my American ear rejects *I and s/he*, but it's not wrong. That's this speaker's preference.

When it comes to *me and **him/her***, it's another story. This speaker puts *me* first, and *I* second (e.g *me and him/her* v. *She/He and I*). Again, *him/her and me* is not wrong, but ***me and s/he*** and ***Him/her and I*** are wrong, regardless of how you arrange them.

> **He's** going to drive **me and *you/him/her/them*** home. **She's** asking about **me/us and *you/him/her/them***. **Who** agrees with
>   **me/us and *him/her/them***?

In conversation, this is **not** a big deal. Only in the most formal contexts--like, say, a job interview, or in front of people *whom* you'd like to impress--would it matter.

In formal writing, always use *subject pronouns* (e.g. I, you, he/she/it, we, you (pl), they, who) to represent *subjects* and object pronouns (e.g. me, you, him/her/it, us, you (pl), them, whom) for objects (i.e. direct and indirect objects and the objects of prepositions).

That's the most important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the reference to yourself last, as a matter of politeness:

- Him and I
- Him and me

To determine easily whether to use "I" or "me", remove the reference to the other party, so:
"Her and me collected some things from the store" becomes "me collected some things from the store", which is clearly wrong; however, "I collected some things from the store" is correct, so by expansion, use "She and I collected some things from the store". "This ice-cream is for me" would become "These ice-creams are for her and me".